# Testing if fields are null ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to create a SQL statement in MS Access that will look for blank fields in a table. Say, for example, a patients last name is missing - this query should pick this up.

How would I go about doing this? I'm able to determine how to do it for the first record but for an entire table is proving difficult

```
Dim Rst As recordSet
Dim f As Field

'Current Record set
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblWebMeetingData")

'Holds current fields data
Dim fieldData

'With Rst
    'Do Until Rst.EOF
       For Each f In Rst.Fields
            If IsNull(f.Value) Then
                MsgBox ("Field Name: " & f.Name)
            End If
       Next
    'Loop
'End With

Rst.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More elegantly:

```
Dim i As String
i = "tblWebMeetingData"
Dim j As Integer
Dim rst As Recordset

' For each Field in the table
For j = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).Fields.Count - 1
    ' Return the number of lines that are null
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT count(*) FROM " & CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).Name & " WHERE " & CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).Fields(j).Name & " IS NULL")
    rst.MoveFirst
    ' Check if it's more than one
    If rst.Fields(0).Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).Fields(j).Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: this worked a treat but I had to add the [] because some of the field names have spaces - kudos!

Comment: kind of a follow up but how would i go about finding the exact row this occurred in?

Comment: Instead of `count(*)`, you can use the key. It would return the key for every field that is null. Then, you would have to add a `Do until rst.EOF` to loop through all the results.

Comment: Also, if you would like to loop through all tables of the database, simplify replace `Dim i As String` for `Dim i As Integer` and add a for loop, from `0 to CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count - 1` while checking that it is not a system table (easily verified by `If Left(CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then`).

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your code would do what you want if you use `MoveNext` before `Loop`.  I make a few other minor changes in this version.

```
Dim Rst As DAO.recordSet
Dim f As DAO.Field
Dim db As DAO.Database

'Current Record set
Set db = CurrentDb
Set Rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblWebMeetingData", dbOpenTable, dbOpenSnapshot)

With Rst
    Do While Not .EOF
       For Each f In .Fields
            If IsNull(f.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Field Name: " & f.Name
            End If
       Next
       .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

Rst.Close
```

However, in the question you said you want to *"create a SQL statement in MS Access that will look for blank fields in a table*".  But, instead of a query you showed us VBA code which inspects a `DAO.Recordset`.  I'm not sure what you really want.

Comment: oh sorry bad wording - i meant SQL code in regards to a query

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
Public Sub CheckNull(FieldName as String)
    Dim rs as DAO.RecordSet

    Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT IDField FROM tblMyTable WHERE " & FieldName & " Is Null")

    If rs.eof then exit sub

    Do until rs.Eof
        debug.print rs!IDField
        rs.movenext
    Loop
End Sub
```

This should in code lookup all records where *FieldName* is Null and then print the results to the immediate window where you pass the FieldName as a string.